# making my thread to wait without blocking the child threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Here is the sample of what I am doing in my Android application

```
public OnClickListener onSelectBtnClicked = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        method1();
        method2();
    }
    private void method1() {
            Interface.API1();
        }

     private void method2() {
        Interface.API2();
    }

};
```

Here I am trying to use an external library so I will be calling their API's to get some work done. Now when I click the button,it will call method1 and then method2

The problem here is when the method1 is called it will call the API1 and API1 will return the status, but it will create some threads internally and start some downloading task. Since API1 returns immediately, my program proceeds to method2 and start calling API2

I need a way to make my program to wait for my API1 to finish its tasks

I tried, `Thread.sleep` and `wait and notify`, both doesn't work as it stops the main thread and it also pauses the thread which API is creating

Any suggestions to make my program wait or any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why not use a handler

Comment: use a Thread, call it a ThredManager, to start other threads and use a countdownlatch to sync

Comment: in Android, there is [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you (the library) using `AsyncTasks`?

If so, I think you have problems because of different API behaviour...

From Honeycomb onwards, threads are using a single thread pool, meaning there is always ONLY one thread running... Resulting in following, that if one thread is blocked, all other threads are blocked as well...
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29, point "Order of execution"

To solve that, you (the library) would have to use `AsyncTask` with a `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`...

Comment: now it makes sense on why I am facing the problem. I am not aware of exactly what is being done inside the library, as it is written by a different team. Is there anything I can do in my code to achieve what I need ?

Comment: Are you using `AsyncTasks`? I think, if not, you have another problem... I edited my post and removed to comment to threads... The `AsyncTasks` have a common thread pool... If you use threads, they will be independent... every thread is a new parallel thread then...